Why can't my Mac make phone calls?
My iPhone is not currently allowing calls using this Mac. I’d like help to troubleshoot and enable this feature.
iPhone Settings > Cellular > Allow Calls on Other Devices is off. I tried to turn it on:

Cannot Turn On Calls on Other Devices — FaceTime and iCloud must be signed in to the same Apple ID to enable Calls on Other Devices.

iPhone Settings > FaceTime is on.
iPhone/Settings/General/About
I opened FaceTime on my Mac, Settings > Calls from phone is checked.
What might I be missing?

To avoid stating the obvious, is FaceTime on your iPhone signed into the same account as iCloud? Can you try signing out of FaceTime and signing back in

Are you using a VPN? I have a MacBook Pro and an iPhone, but for as long as I can remember I have been unable to take and make phone calls via my MacBook when I activate a VPN connection (ExpressVPN) on my MBP. I can do either, however, when I deactivate the VPN connection.

I would turn off everything you have on and then verify in order the requirements. You didn’t mention WiFi calling, so that might be the missing item. (Assuming your iOS meets the iOS 8 and Mac is 10.9 or later requirements)

https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/aside/glos887021a/mac

Main items to validate are:

Your iPhone and Mac have Wi-Fi Calling turned on and use the exact same AppleID for FaceTime ( contact Apple support  if you use different iCloud Apple ID or messages or FaceTime - I’m not sure I can test that situation and know some people use more than one Apple ID for continuity. App Store is generally safe to use an alternate, but iCloud services work best with only one Apple ID per person and cell number)
Your iPhone and Mac are on the same Wi-Fi network and connected to the internet.
Bluetooth on (this is a good general continuity item for all features using Apple ID and iCloud sharing)

For more details see the FaceTime calling guide and continuity guide from Apple support.

https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/make-and-receive-phone-calls-mchl390e9463/mac

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-across-devices-using-continuity-mchl1d734309/mac



I turned every setting off then on, that didn't do anything.
But on my phone, I went to Settings/FaceTime and found a setting that I don't see now.  It gave me an option of using my AppleID or a different account, looking like it was using my AppleID.  I touched it,   My other devices notified me that my iPhone and Apple Watch were added to FaceTime.  And I was able to turn Allow calls using other devices.
I've never had a desire to use FaceTime, but I have wanted to make phone calls using my Mac.  I guess that means using FaceTime.
